# In DDEV how can I install non-Debian packages like PECL, npm, pip, etc

Tags: ddev

I want to install some software like a [MySQL CLI tool](https://github.com/dbcli/mycli) and [the docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/customizing-images/) say `.ddev/config.yaml` can be edited to add extra debian packages... but what about non-debian packages?  How do you install something that would normally be installed via `pip install -U mycli`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Edit 2020-04-10: The approach here is written up more extensively in [Customizing DDEV-Local images with a custom Dockerfile](https://ddev.com/ddev-local/customizing-ddev-local-images-with-a-custom-dockerfile/)]

The mysql CLI tool (mysql) is already installed in both the ddev web and db containers, but you definitely like [mycli](https://github.com/dbcli/mycli).

As you know, most popular Linux tools have Debian packages, and it's easy to install those using `webimage_extra_packages: [package1, package2]` per https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/customizing-images/#adding-extra-debian-packages-with-webimage_extra_packages-and-dbimage_extra_packages

In your case, mycli is distributed as a Debian package per its github page, so you can just use `webimage_extra_packages: [mycli]`, and that's the best way to install it.

But to automatically install other tools when the container is built (which use npm or pip3 or pecl/pear or whatever) you'd use a [custom Dockerfile](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/customizing-images/#adding-extra-dockerfiles-for-webimage-and-dbimage). We'll use your example of mycli (as if it didn't have a Debian package).

In .ddev/web-build/Dockerfile you'd want something like this, based on .ddev/web-build/Dockerfile.example, which first installs pip3 and then uses that to install mycli:

```
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confnew" --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests python3-pip python3-setuptools
RUN pip3 install mycli
```

Of course for npm packages we could take the example from the Dockerfile.example, `RUN npm install --global gulp-cli`. And it's even possible to install gcc or g++ (just as we installed pip3) and build a package from source.

If you wanted to install a PECL/Pear package, the approach in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60554990/215713 will be work.  It's the same basic idea.

The great thing about the custom Dockerfile (or `webimage_extra_packages`, when it's needed, is that the Docker image containing the extra instructions only needs to be built once per configuration, not on every startup. Note though that a custom Dockerfile overrides `webimage_extra_packages`, so they're mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thanks Randy!  This is really great because debian packages are so often out of date (and sometimes very out of date) and it's great to see examples installing something with pip!

Comment: For installing python3, I added the following lines to the config.yml 
`webimage_extra_packages: [python3, python-is-python3]`
And following lines on the docker file (.ddev/web-build/Dockerfile)
`ARG BASE_IMAGE
FROM $BASE_IMAGE
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confnew" --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests python3 python-is-python3 python3-pip python3-setuptools
RUN pip3 install mycli`

Comment: See also, a dedicated DDEV howto for Python 2 and 3 here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70585745/413538