# How to add Python and pip or conda packages to DDEV

Tags: python, docker, ddev

I need to execute a Python script inside the [Ddev](https://ddev.com/) web docker image, but am having trouble figuring out what [Debian python libraries](https://packages.debian.org/stable/python/) are required to get Python binary with additional py package dependencies working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Python 2 on DDEV

You really don’t want to be using Python 2 do you? (See caveats 1 & 2 below)

Add the following in `.ddev/config.yml`:

```yaml
webimage_extra_packages: [python]
```

If your Python 2 scripts need additional package dependencies installed via `pip`, you'll need to instead use a custom Dockerfile:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE
FROM $BASE_IMAGE
RUN apt-key adv --refresh-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com \
  && apt update
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests python python-pip
RUN pip install somepackage anotherpackage
```

Note: a custom Dockerfile will override `webimage_extra_packages` configurations in `.ddev/config.yaml`.

Caveat 1: As of 2022, DDEV web image runs Debian 11 and `sudo apt-get python` still installs Python 2. This *may change* in future versions of Debian, so be careful when you upgrade DDEV.

Caveat 2: Python 2 has reached its *End Of Life* and is unsupported. Additionally, important package manager `pip` is no longer able to natively install (without workarounds) on latest Python 2, so you're probably better off upgrading your scripts to Python 3 using the `2to3` utility.

## Python 3 on DDEV

Use the following Ddev configuration to install Python 3 into /usr/bin/python along with most of any additional package dependencies for your py scripts.

```yaml
webimage_extra_packages: [python3, python-is-python3]
```

Note that by default, Python 3 is installed to `/usr/bin/python3` so add the `python-is-python3` package to make `python` execute Python 3.

You can also usually work around needing to install the `python3-pip` package, because most Python 3 packages are already bundled for Debian. Therefore, additional Python 3 package dependencies can be added by comma-separated name to `webimage_extra_packages`. See [list of stable Python packages for Debian here](https://packages.debian.org/stable/python/).

If your dependencies are not bundled and you need to use `pip`, Conda, or another python package manager, then you must implement a custom Dockerfile at `.ddev/web-image/Dockerfile` like this:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE
FROM $BASE_IMAGE
RUN apt-key adv --refresh-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com \
  && apt update
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests python3 python-is-python3 python3-pip
RUN pip3 install somepackage anotherpackage
```

Note: a custom Dockerfile will override `webimage_extra_packages` configurations in `.ddev/config.yaml`.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you so much for this guide -- I'm doing a `yarn install` with a set-up that mandates Python 2, and also needs `make`

Following your advice, I used:

`webimage_extra_packages: [build-essential, python]`

per https://techoverflow.net/2018/06/04/fixing-npm-node-gyp-error-not-found-make-on-ubuntu/

Next, I had another error related to my version of NodeJS being too new, so I downgraded that:

`nodejs_version: "14"`

Per the instructions here:

https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/cli-usage/#nodejs-npm-nvm-and-yarn

Finally everything installed correctly.